# Detect scroll event from inner div

Tags: angular

I want to be able to detect events when scrolling from a scrollable inner div not just a window target.

For example i have a Directive which listen for scroll events, here I need to change ' host: '(window:scroll)' to something else.

```
import {Directive, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[infinite-scroll]',
  host: {'(window:scroll)': 'track($event)'},
})

export class InfiniteScrollerDirective {
  @Output() scrolled = new EventEmitter();

  track(event: Event) {
    this.scrolled.emit({
        value: event
    });
  }
}
```

I use it in my component as infinite-scroll directive with "scrolled" output.

```
<div infinite-scroll (scrolled)="onScroll($event.value)">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>...
```

And event goes here.

```
 onScroll(event: UIEvent) {

 }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Does the `<div infinite-scroll>` not fire `scrolled` events?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/BFAK87jCR81dcBbz5HxS?p=preview

Comment: Does this link help `naive_infinite_scroll/scroll_area.ts` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bb8976608db93b9ff90a71187608a4390cbd7a07/modules/benchmarks/src/naive_infinite_scroll/scroll_area.ts

Comment: The problem is that scroll events only fire on window scroll not inner div scroll.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use the (scroll) event, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949987/detect-scroll-event-on-element-nativeelement-angular

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure why everyone here is trying to mess with the @HostListener. It is definitely required when working with page level events, but not child elements.  Instead of going with JQuery style event binding, you can use Angular 2 event listeners. If you're working with an inner-div, all you need to do is add the scroll event listener on your div with a callback method like the following:

HTML:

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">

</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
onScroll(event): void {

    // Interpret the scroll event
    // Do stuff on inner div scroll
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2.0 RC

```
export class YourComponent {
      @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) private onScroll($event:Event):void {
        console.log($event.srcElement.scrollLeft, $event.srcElement.scrollTop);
      };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to add manually EventListner

```
    document.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=>{
        let el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        if(el.contains(e.target)){
        // do something
        }
    }, true);
```

The "true" at the end tells the browser to capture the event on dispatch, even if that event does not normally bubble, like change, focus, and scroll.

It isn't possible pass useCapture parameter to @HostListener or renderer.listen.

Do not forget to remove this listener, when you destroy component.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [`'in-viewpoint'` Directive](https://k3nsei.github.io/ng-in-viewport/) you could attach to custom elements:

```
const CUSTOM_ELEMENT = this.elementRef.nativeElement || window; 
this.scrollWindow = Observable
      .fromEvent(CUSTOM_ELEMENT, 'scroll').debounceTime(50).subscribe((event) => {
        this.fireScrollEvent();
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

**The `div` which you want to capture `scroll` event from should be scrollable .**

To make it scrollable

1. It should have a proper height.
2. Then add `overflow: scroll`  to style.

After doing above you will  get scroll event from any `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <div id="my-inner-div" (scroll)="onScroll()">
      <!-- content here -->
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  
  fixedHeader: boolean = false

  onScroll() {
    this.fixedHeader = true;
  }
}
```

> To make it scrollable it shoude be use (scroll) in div

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34426333)