# Detect scroll event on element.nativeElement angular

Tags: angular, scroll

I am using angular 8.2 and want to detect scroll event on `elementRef.nativeElement`.
I have tried various ways:

1. renderer2
2. addEventListener
3. rxJs

however, No luck.

Yes, definitely I can track event using `document` and `window`. but I want to detect on specific element.

I am using directive for the same.

I have seen that this requirement is working with rxJS 5.x and angular 4.x | 5.x. but not with angular 8.x to latest.

working example with angular 4.x and rxJs 5.x  https://ashwin-sureshkumar.github.io/angular-infinite-scroller/

non working [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-io) with latest angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual scroll code is fine. The reason it's not working in the Angular 8 version is that you're scrolling on the page, not on the `div`. The difference between the two is that the working example has a fixed height with `overflow: scroll` whereas the non-working example has the `div` taking up its entire height.

To get it to work, you can simply add the following css to the `.scrolling-guy` div:

```
height: 500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

[Working example](https://lazy-load-io-tjpwyu.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can detect scrolling on a specific element using `@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])`, it would make the most sense to create a directive so you can add the functionality on any object.

Here is an example on how to add it in a component (so it will listen to scroll events on the component element itself):

```
@HostListener("scroll", ["$event"]) private onScroll($event: any): void {
  console.log($event.srcElement.scrollLeft, $event.srcElement.scrollTop);
}
```

and you can see this live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zh3kgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)